# Double gaussian fit with common centroid Python

Tags: python, data-fitting

I am trying to fit some data with a double Gaussian function using `scipy.optimization.curve_fit`:

[Double gaussian fit with two centroids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSerh.png)

```
def _2gaussian(x, amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2):
    g1 = amp1 * (1 / (sigma1 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen1) / sigma1) ** 2)))
    g2 = amp2 * (1 / (sigma2 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen2) / sigma2) ** 2)))
    return g1 + g2  # + cen2
```

So my problem is: my data are quite symmetric and I was trying to use a double Gaussian fit with a common/shared centroid for the two Gaussian functions. I have tried to write in the previous formula `cen1` instead of `cen2` (and keeping `cen2` in the parameters) or also to just eliminate totally `cen2` as a parameter. Nothing of these worked, so that the fit obtained is just a flat curve with a big spike in the middle. Do you have any suggestions on how to have just a shared centroid?

[Double gaussian with cen1 only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ2zl.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to give a complete minimal working example, with some (generic) data, if possible. Apart from that, did you try providing some reasonable starting values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lowest points in your data start at around y = 4000. But your Gaussian function has no offset term, so it will always start at y = 0. You either need to normalize your data, or add an offset like this:

```
def _2gaussian(x, amp1, cen1, sigma1, amp2, cen2, sigma2, offset):
    g1 = amp1 * (1 / (sigma1 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen1) / sigma1) ** 2)))
    g2 = amp2 * (1 / (sigma2 * (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))) * (np.exp((-1.0 / 2.0) * (((x - cen2) / sigma2) ** 2)))
    return g1 + g2  + offset # + cen2
```

Then I highly recommend using the `p0` argument in `curve_fit`, which will let you specify an initial guess for each parameter in your fitting function. In your case, your guess for `offset` will be 4000.